# R transform data frame columns into single column based on column name split

Tags: r, dataframe, transform, data-cleaning, reshape2

A common data cleaning question, but with a bit of a twist that I'm having trouble executing.

I have a dataset with multiple columns of year.month information like so:

```
    loc      type  2010.01  2010.02  2010.03 
  Manhattan   a      2300     2300     2500     
  Manhattan   b      2999     2975     2975
```

I'd like to transform the data based on the column name, by splitting by year and month at the "."

So the data would look like this:

```
loc        type  year   month  value
Manhattan   a    2010    01     2300
Manhattan   a    2010    02     2300
Manhattan   a    2010    03     2500
Manhattan   b    2010    01     2999
Manhattan   b    2010    02     2975
Manhattan   b    2010    03     2975
```

How can I go about this?

I'm thinking of using melt, something like this but I'm pretty new to R and know this isn't correct:

```
df <- melt(df,id=1,measure=patterns(".",value.name="Value"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this via `pivot_longer` and `separate` from `tidyr`. Try this:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df <- read.table(text = "loc      type  2010.01  2010.02  2010.03 
  Manhattan   a      2300     2300     2500     
  Manhattan   b      2999     2975     2975     ", header = TRUE)
df
#>         loc type X2010.01 X2010.02 X2010.03
#> 1 Manhattan    a     2300     2300     2500
#> 2 Manhattan    b     2999     2975     2975

df %>% 
  pivot_longer(-c(loc:type)) %>% 
  separate(name, into = c("year", "month")) %>% 
  mutate(year = gsub("X", "", year))
#> # A tibble: 6 x 5
#>   loc       type  year  month value
#>   <fct>     <fct> <chr> <chr> <int>
#> 1 Manhattan a     2010  01     2300
#> 2 Manhattan a     2010  02     2300
#> 3 Manhattan a     2010  03     2500
#> 4 Manhattan b     2010  01     2999
#> 5 Manhattan b     2010  02     2975
#> 6 Manhattan b     2010  03     2975
```

<sup>Created on 2020-04-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: wow that's awesome! for my understanding, how does separate() know the value is a year and month? I'm surprised specifying the separator "." wasn't needed

Comment: Because that's what I told `separate` via `into = c("year", "month")`.(; `separate` by default checks for standard separators like ".", "_", ... to split the strings.

Comment: My pleasure. If you want do me a favor: Mark the question as answered. Besides giving me some credit it shows others with a similar problem that the solution worked and removes the question from the queue of questions still waiting for an answer.